# Cannot disable scroll on android browser

Tags: javascript, scroll, android-browser

```
$('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
```

I use this in my javascript file to hide the scroll bar. This works for all browsers except for android browsers. Is there any alternative way to hide the scroll bar for android browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting it on the html element too:

```
$('html, body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
```